# shuttle sh55 not POSTing

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, post

I bought a Shuttle SH55 and an intel I7 1156 to go with it
Since the i7 chip doesnt have integrated graphics, I have to use a separate graphics card
I'm using a GeForce GT240

I only have the video card and CPU in right now, nothing else (no ram, HDD, optical)
I have a monitor plugged into the video card's D-Sub port.

When I turn on the PC, The video card fan and cooling fan for the cpu turns on, but I don't see anything on the screen (and yes, the screen is on)
Any ideas why? Is it just not posting, or is it trying to use the integrated graphics?

edit:
notes:
USB ports aren't powering the keyboard / mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GT240 is just NOT compatible with the Shuttle SH55J motherboard.

Shuttle has a parts compatibility list here:
http://global.shuttle.com/support_list03.jsp?PI=1409
further details on my blog: http://hokuten.net/2010/shuttle-pc-part-2/

I'm now using a compatible ATI Radeon 5770 (which requires 450W minimum, but is running fine on the 300W supply)
I bought an SH55J compatible 500W power supply, too, which I will put in later just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

> I only have the video card and CPU in right now, nothing else (**no ram**, HDD, optical)

Most BIOS won't go beyond POST until you have the RAM plugged in.

Comment: i put in one stick in a red slot and tried it, no go, same with one dimm in a black slot

Comment: Can you post more details ? Processor /  RAM specifications / power supply details / full motherboard serial number?

Comment: Intel i7-860, 1156 / G.Skill Ripjaws 4GB DDR3 1333 / Stock 300W shuttle power supply / SH55J motherboard / GeForce GT 240

Comment: Your power supply might not be sufficient to power the GT 240. Can you disconnect the GT240 and use the onboard GPU ?

Comment: nope, neither the i7 nor the motherboard have onboard GPU

Comment: Can you wire up all the drives and try it ?'m not sure what's the problem here.

Comment: Also, try with the other DIMM.